# Deprecated offline_access on facebook with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth, koala

We have a problem in our RoR app. We are using a facebook authentication with omniauth, and searching the user friends with Koala. But lately, when we try to show a friend photo, we got this error:

```
Koala::Facebook::APIError in Homes#show

Showing /home/daniel/Homes/app/views/shared/_event.html.erb where line #19 raised:

OAuthException: Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1328727600. The current unix time is 1328802133.
Extracted source (around line #19):

16:     <img src="../assets/friends-icon.png" alt="User  profile apicture" height="33" width="43">
17:         <% if current_user %>
18:           <% event.friends_in_event(@person).each do |f| %>
19:             <%= link_to(image_tag(f.fb_picture, :size => "43x33"), person_path(f.id)) %>
20:           <% end %>
21:         <% end %>
22:       </div>
```

The authentication works good, but facebook has already deprecated the offline_access option, that was working good, but now, we have this issue.
is It any way to extends the access_token?, or are there another solution?.

This is our omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FB_KEY'], ENV['FB_SECRET'], 
  { :scope => 'email,offline_access,user_photos,publish_stream',
    :client_options => { :ssl => { :ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs" } } }
end
```

And our koala.rb

```
Koala.http_service.http_options = {
  :ssl => { :ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs" }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 solutions to this problem:

- **Extend the user's access token:**

  - As per [this article on the Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/), you may request a 60-day extension on a user's access token. However, if the user does not return within that period, this method won't help you.
  - You can find a PHP code snippet to do this [at this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9035036/259465).

    1. To do this, send a post to this API endpoint: `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN`

---

- **Catch the `OAuthException` and request a new access token:**

  - Facebook provides a PHP code snippet outlining this solution [on their dev blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/).
  - Basically, you follow these steps:

    1. Make a call to the graph with the user's current `access_token`.
    2. If the call succeeds, the `access_token` is fine. If it throws an `OAuthException`, redirect the user to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL`
    3. The user will be sent to that URL and then redirected to your `CALLBACK_URL` with a `code` in the parameters.
    4. Send a post to the following URL with the `code` to obtain a new `access_token`: `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL&client_secret=APP_SECRET&code=CODE&display=popup`

Read the post on their dev blog for more information.

**Edit (adding example Ruby on Rails code):**

Add the following to the top of your `ApplicationController`:

```
rescue_from Koala::Facebook::APIError, :with => :handle_fb_exception
```

Add the following `protected` method to your `ApplicationController`:

```
def handle_fb_exception exception
  if exception.fb_error_type.eql? 'OAuthException'
    logger.debug "[OAuthException] Either the user's access token has expired, they've logged out of Facebook, deauthorized the app, or changed their password"
    oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new

    # If there is a code in the url, attempt to request a new access token with it
    if params.has_key? 'code'
      code = params['code']
      logger.debug "We have the following code in the url: #{code}"
      logger.debug "Attempting to fetch a new access token..."
      token_hash = oauth.get_access_token_info code
      logger.debug "Obtained the following hash for the new access token:"
      logger.debug token_hash.to_yaml
      redirect_to root_path
    else # Since there is no code in the url, redirect the user to the Facebook auth page for the app
      oauth_url = oauth.url_for_oauth_code :permissions => 'email'
      logger.debug "No code was present; redirecting to the following url to obtain one: #{oauth_url}"
      redirect_to oauth_url
    end
  else
    logger.debug "Since the error type is not an 'OAuthException', this is likely a bug in the Koala gem; reraising the exception..."
    raise exception
  end
end
```

The Koala calls were all taken from the following 2 tutorials:

- https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/OAuth
- https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Koala-on-Rails

Comment: I already read that documentation, but I need a solution for RoR not PHP.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who don't have time to make this change, I found that you can disable this migration in Settings -> Advanced. The name of the option is "Remove offline_access permission:"