# Can I extend the acces token which has already expired

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

Facebook has deprecated the offline_access and introduced access token extension instead.
The doc says that to extend access token we need to provide a valid access token. 
Now my doubt is can I pass an access token which has already expired to the url,-
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=EXPIRED_ACCESS_TOKEN

Note:- the user hasn't changed the password nor he has revoked the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can exchange it for a longer-lived token while it's still active, but once it expires it stops working and you'll need to wait for the user to return to your app and get a new access token for them

Answer (score 1):

Passing an expired or invalid access token to the extension endpoint will return an error. You can only extend access tokens that are currently valid.

Facebook provides a way to request a new access token with no user interaction. Please see my detailed solution to this problem, complete with code, here: [Deprecated offline_access on facebook with RoR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214671/deprecated-offline-access-on-facebook-with-ror/9216785#9216785)