# how to extend facebook access token to 60 days

Tags: php, facebook, access-token

I am doing a facebook canvas project. But now, I do really hope that someone can do me a favour, because I think I am facing a problem which might be related to the "access token". The situation is I have to login to my app again and again after every hour, it seems that the access token will be expired in an hour after you login (actually I really don't know how to extend it), and I'd searched on Google.com and stackoverflow.com, but still can't get the answer I want, so I hope that someone can solve my question.

Many thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has deprecated offline_access permission, so you have to extend access token manually, read more here..
[How to extend access token validity since offline_access deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation)

Answer (score 1):

To extend the access token facebook provides user interface to do it with ease.
Just click on the following link put your access token and hit the extend your acccess token.

(* For more detail your follow the link :  -http://techpost360.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-extend-facebook-access-token.html)

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

[image]