# How to do an http request and then retrieving the token?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a facebook application, so I need to do an http request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

to get a string like this:

```
token=AAABz7kfdgXPwmgBANKZCctdZCPdfgfgcRJ0ONpQr8cWr336dfZDZD&expires=5168309
```

and then I need to retrieve the token:

```
AAABz7kfdgXPwmgBANKZCctdZCPdfgfgcRJ0ONpQr8cWr336dfZDZD
```

What do I have to use to do that ? curl library ? or is there a simplest way ?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't reinvent the wheel like that.
Instead, use the existing PHP SDK:

- https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Comment: You're right, but it's a good practice to understand the facebook api logic. ^^

Comment: For some people it might be a good idea to actually know how OAuth and other specifics of the Facebook API work, but in most cases, and I believe that includes xRobots', it's completely unnecessary

Comment: What does it mean ? "and I believe that includes xRobots"

Comment: in xRobots' (thats the OP) case ;)

Comment: I can't use the php sdk to retrieve the long-lived token: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation

Answer (score 0):

That's it !

```
function getAccessTok($code){
    if($code !== null){
        $urlTok = $urlGraphFB.'oauth/access_token';
        $urlTok .= '?client_id='.$appID;
        $urlTok .= '&redirect_uri='.$redirect_uri;
        $urlTok .= '&client_secret='.$_appSECRET;
        $urlTok .= '&code='.$code;

        $fileacctok = parse_str(file_get_contents($urlTok));
        return $fileacctok;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want my custom facebook class i can give it to you. It's pretty easy to use, but can't do everything. You can use curl to replace the file_get_content... When i create it i didn't know curl yet.

Comment: what is the different from curl and file_get_content ?