# Will access token work when user is offline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have read [offline-access-removal](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) , [how to handle expired tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/) and [How to extend access token validity since offline_access deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation/9035036#9035036) too.

They tell about deprecation of offline access_token and a way to get 60 days long token.

But I have a very basic question.

**Will I be able to post on behalf of user even when he/she is not online ?** 
(ofcourse for 60 days with extended token )

*In my next project, I need to post to user's page and wall from a rss feed automatically before user interaction. Will I be able to do so for 60 days ?*

If your answer is yes,
whats the [Scenario 4: User logs out of Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work. Though, this is TIAS question (try it and see).

In response to the edited question, "if the users logs out" – your access token will remain valid. That is still the same question.

Comment: yes, if I were you, I would have suggested the OP to try it and see but I thought I would get some insights and more related info or hacks to make access token work even after 60 days.

Comment: Also whats the scenario 4 [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/)

Comment: @Jashwant The question requires a straightforward answer (yes/no). Any advice on "how to make access token work beyond 60 days" would be against Facebook TOS. The reference link you've provided yourself.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct and what I have desired . I would mark it as answer :) But I am asking about the scenario 4

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

**You Can** post on user wall even the user signout from facebook (its also my personal experience i post on my behalf with my 60 days access_token and get the post data from database) all is work

I guess you still confuse so whats the **logs out**  mean i guess here is the logs out mean that user deactivate his/her account

think if here the logs out mean logout/signout than whats the benefit of 60 days access_token

**here is the logs out means totally logged out from account**

Hope this will solve you confusion