# Simplest solution to use CRON to update a FB page

Tags: facebook, cron, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-access-token

I have spent a long time searching the API docs and google for a solution and really haven't been able to find a solution that meets my needs. So my question is simple, what would be the most simple way for me to use cron + php to make a facebook post for a page?

Comment: Run a php script from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Use Simple **Feed** API of fb with the **access_token**.

1. If you are posting as the app, you'll be needing the access_token of the app (which never expires). You can get the token from here: [AccessTokens](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/)
2. If you to post on behalf of a user, you'll be needing the access_token of the user.
   The normal access token expires in 2 hours, and the extended token lasts for 2 months. 
   Use the extended token for the cron job. Ref: [How to extend access token validity since offline_access deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation/9035036#9035036)