# Facebook Extended access token server side with client side login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using client side sdk for Login and in server side php sdk for 'wall posting' on a triggered action using graph api ( I was using it with offline_access but now I know its deprecated ).

How to get ***Extended access token*** in Server-side using client side sdk so that I can use the extended token in server side,

I know some answers are there like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation/9035036#9035036), but they use Server-side login and get extended token from $_REQUEST['code'] which they get in response,

I there any way that I can get the value of $_REQUEST['code'] using client side login?

**Update:**

My client login code supports oAuth:

```
FB.init({
  appId      : 'MYAPPID', // App ID
  status     : true,  // check login status
  cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access  the session
  xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
  oauth      : true   // enable OAuth 2.0
});  

FB.login(function() {
   FB.api('/me', {'fields': "some coma seperated fields"},
      function(response){ 
        //Function that sends data to server
        Pass_data_to_server( response );
      });    
}, scope:'some scope values');
```

**Server side code:**

```
<?php
  $settings = array
  (
    'appId'  => FB_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true,
    'oauth'  => true
  );    

  // Get facebook object from facebook sdk class
  $facebook  = new Facebook($settings); 

  if ($facebook)
  {                              
    $user_id   = $facebook->getUser();      

    $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken(); //long-live access_token 60 days
    $token     = $facebook->getAccessToken();            
    try 
    {                      
      $response = $facebook->api('me/og.like', 'POST',{ $MYCUSTOMDATA});
      return $response;
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
      print_r($e)
      return false;          
    }        
  }
?>
```

Comment: Aren't you having access token on server side also, considering the fact that you are posting on User's wall from server side

Comment: @AnveshSaxena yes I have an access token, But that will expire soon after I can post once, but for the next post it gave an error "an active access token must be used"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [extend](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/) your access token using the Facebook PHP SDK method

```
setExtendedAccessToken()
```

This will automatically extend your short term extended access token by calling the end point

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
client_id=APP_ID&
client_secret=APP_SECRET&
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

You can then save this access token for authorizing the requests for next 60 days.

Comment: I have updated My client side and server side code in my question, I am using updated PHP sdk from github, still im not able to make it work

Comment: Yes, As I told you I can post once using the access token, but for the next post it returns error saying "an active access token must be used".

Comment: Could you check if the User even remains logged in when you move between the pages?

Comment: User remains logged in, one more thing I am not storing access token, I am calling set Access token again for next request. Should I store the access token ?

Comment: Access token is stored in the session, what are you setting the access token to in the next page. You can also debug whether there is any problem in access token by printing it and checking it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token)